# How can I create reactor Flux from a blocking queue?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am trying to implement a reactor Flux created from a BlockingQueue but not sure which operator is best for my use case?

I am creating a streaming REST end point, where response is Flux that needs to keep emitting messages from a BlockingQueue as a response to GET REST call.

I have already tried forums and documentation and can only find Flux initiated from iterable collections or reactive data sources, but no examples from any BlockingQueue.

Comment: Add some more description or your code snippet so that others can understand your issue and help you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try [Flux#generate](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#generate-java.util.concurrent.Callable-java.util.function.BiFunction-) and [Queue#peek](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#peek()). Just keep in mind that `peek` will return `null` if the queue is empty, and it cannot be used in `onNext`.

Something like:

```java
Flux.generate(sink -> {
    val element = queue.peek();
    if (element == null) {
        sink.complete();
    } else {
        sink.next(element);
    }
});
```

There is also [Flux#repeatWhen](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#repeatWhen-java.util.function.Function-) operator, in case you want to re-subscribe to the queue after it was considered empty, e.g. with:

```java
flux.repeatWhen(it -> it.delayElements(ofSeconds(1)))
```

Comment: It worked. Although, my client(browser) kept sending request again and again once server signalled sink complete. So i changed to BlockingQueue#take. Not sure how that fits into the reactive asynchronous processing.

Comment: Be careful because `#take` is blocking. Make sure you subscribe on blocking-friendly scheduler (e.g. `Schedulers.elastic()`)

Comment: @bsideup, why is the `peek()` used here instead of the `poll()` to remove element from the queue once it has been pipelined?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative worth considering is to get rid of BlockingQueue and use Sinks instead.

This requires:

1. Creating a sink, e.g.

   ```
   private final Sinks.Many<String> sink = Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer();
   ```
2. Exposing a sink as a Flux:

   ```
   sink.asFlux()
   ```
3. Pushing to a sink:

   ```
   sink.tryEmitNext("SOME MESSAGE");
   ```